# Cloudbuild.yaml with enviroment variables?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

I have cloud build file something like this

```
steps:

- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        pytest -rP

#- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
#  args:
#  - functions
#  - deploy
#  - Test_Function
#  - --runtime=python37
#  - --source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/proj_name/repos/repo_name/moveable-aliases/master/paths/function
#  - --entry-point=main
#  - --trigger-topic=Test_Topic
#  - --region=region
```

-now what i would like to do is i would like to define soemthing like a variable (Test_name) or in enviroment variables and put that variable in different lines in my yaml like this below.

```
Test_name: "my_name"
steps:

- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        pytest -rP

#- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
#  args:
#  - functions
#  - deploy
#  - **{Test_name}**_Function
#  - --runtime=python37
#  - --source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/proj_name/repos/repo_name/moveable-aliases/master/paths/function
#  - --entry-point=main
#  - --trigger-topic=**{Test_name}**_Topic
#  - --region=region
```

how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Cloud Build's substitutions to achieve that, as stated in the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#using_user-defined_substitutions).

Following the samples provided in the aforementioned docs, your `cloudbuild.yaml` will look like:

```
Test_name: "my_name"
steps:

- name: 'python:3.7'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args: 
    - '-c'
    - |
        pip3 install -r requirements.txt
        pytest -rP

#- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
#  args:
#  - functions
#  - deploy
#  - ${_TEST_NAME}_Function
#  - --runtime=python37
#  - --source=https://source.developers.google.com/projects/proj_name/repos/repo_name/moveable-aliases/master/paths/function
#  - --entry-point=main
#  - --trigger-topic=${_TEST_NAME}_Topic
#  - --region=region

substitutions:
    TEST_NAME: TEST # default value
```

Comment: i have tried it too but gave me this error...ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) argument --trigger-topic: Invalid value '$(_TEST_NAME)_Topic': Topic must contain only Latin letters (lower- or upper-case), digits and the characters - + . _ ~ %. It must start with a letter and be from 3 to 255 characters long.

Comment: Have you used curly brackets`{}` instead of normal brackets `()`? Also what was the value of your env variable?

Comment: No problem, glad that could be of help!